# Why array.prototype.map() returns the old value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, socket.io

I have created the chat app and trying to make real-time last message displaying in the contacts' field. It's working but not how I wanted it to be. I want update last message when new message appears in the chat container. Right now it's updating last message, but does it on the second try and displaying the first one's last message.

For example: 1st message: "1"
2nd message: "2"

It will display "1" despite "2" has already appeared in the chat container and shown in console. Here is the code of map:

```
{chats.map((chat) => {
   return (
     <div key={chat._id}>
        {chat.latestMessage && (
            <div>
               <span>{chat.latestMessage.sender.username} : </span>
                   {chat.latestMessage.content.length}
            </div>
         )}
     </div>
)}
```

Here is the code of socket:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (socket.current) {
      socket.current.on('contacts', (data) => {
        setCt(data);
      });
      newChat();
      setChats(cht);
    } else {
      console.log("socket doesn't connected")
    }
});
```

And the newChat function:

```
const newChat = async () => {
    if (cht !== undefined && cht.length !== 0 && ct !== undefined) {
      cht.map((chat) => {
        var temp = Object.assign({}, chat);
        if (temp._id === ct._id) {
          temp.latestMessage.content = ct.latestMessage.content;
        }
        return temp;
      });
      return cht;
    };
  };
```

I have tried to do it without adding new `useState` hooks like `ct` and `cht`, but for now left them

Comment: [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array with new elements mapped from original ones. You did not assign it to anything: `/* const newCht = */ cht.map(...)`.

Comment: @InSync I don't think it's correct to declare a variable inside the html code

Comment: That notation (valid JS comment, mind you) is just to let you know what you may need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `newChat` function is returning a result based on `ct` but this latter is not updated yet, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75844926/13488990).

Also the function is returning `cht` but the code inside it is not really updating `cht` (you can't even do that) you should return the array created by the map function instead, then give it to `setChats()`

```js
const newChat = (data) => {
    if (cht !== undefined && cht.length !== 0 && data !== undefined) {
     return cht.map((chat) => {
        var temp = Object.assign({}, chat);
        if (temp._id === data._id) {
          temp.latestMessage.content = data.latestMessage.content;
        }
        return temp;
      });     
    };
};
```

Finally update your `useEffect` and get rid of `ct`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (socket.current) {
    socket.current.on("contacts", (data) => {
    setChats(newChat(data));
    });
  } else {
    console.log("socket doesn't connected");
  }
});
```